# Counter on Bootstrap 3 Carousel doesn't show correct number of slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a twitter bootstrap 3 carousel, and have some javascript to show the current slide and the number of slides in the carousel.

The problem I'm having is that the counter doesn't display the count until the carousel has moved one slide, then it shows correctly. (eg. ist should show 1/ (number of slides) on load, but it doesn show anything till you've clicked a carousel nav arrow.

I've added the javascript code below and a example of the context in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1pv3e87t/8/)

```
$('.carousel-stats').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');
var currentIndex = carouselData.getItemIndex(carouselData.$element.find('.item.active'))
var total = carouselData.$items.length;

// display the count in a id with a tag for styling
var text = (currentIndex + 1) + " / " + total;
$('#carousel-index-stats').text(text);
});
```

I not sure whether the error is in my actual code, or just a typo somewhere but I've been staring at it for a hour, and am non the wiser. Any help/ guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntaxt error, check the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

You have to change the event to

```
$('.carousel-stats').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
```

As the documentation says

```
slide.bs.carousel   This event fires immediately when the slide instance method is invoked.
slid.bs.carousel    This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.
```

Comment: I've tried altering the event as you suggested, but the count still remains blank until the first scroll event, I'm not sure if it's the syntax causing the issue. See http://jsfiddle.net/1pv3e87t/10/

Comment: Yes you are right, both events fire when the slide start and when the slide end. You can initialise the counter with a function just after you declare the carousel, see this fiddle as an example http://jsfiddle.net/1pv3e87t/12/